# Similaridade de elementos em diferentes vetores

Tags: r, array, grep

Tenho dois vetores:

```
A <- c("RS", "DF", "CE")
B <- c("Porto Alegre - RS", "Brasília - DF", "Fortaleza - CE", "Porto Alegre - RS", 
"Acre - AC", "Recife - PE")
```

e uma função:

```
f <- function(a,b) {
  lista <- grep(a,b, fixed = FALSE)
  return(lista)
}
mm <- lapply(A, B, FUN = f)
```

Estou obtendo a posição dos elementos de A em B, mas preciso dos elementos de B e não a posição.

Pensei que isso funcionaria:

```
B[mm]
```

Mas não deu. Como faço isso?

Comment: isso é R? formate o código, coloque as tags da linguagem, vai ajudar sua pergunta ter mais visibilidade

Comment: É R sim, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: de nada, é só dar up ali xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O resultado de `lapply(A, B, FUN = f)` é uma lista. Rode

```
B[unlist(mm)]
```

que o resultado vai ser o desejado:

```
[1] "Porto Alegre - RS" "Porto Alegre - RS" "Brasília - DF"    
[4] "Fortaleza - CE"
```

Se quiser obter os resultados únicos, sem repetição, faça

```
unique(B[unlist(mm)])
[1] "Porto Alegre - RS" "Brasília - DF"     "Fortaleza - CE"
```